# ng-click triggering twice in iOs divice only

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

I am using ng-click for div which will filter the data. I am using collection-repeat to show large data.

When the data is less, the click only triggers once, but when the data is huge, the click triggers twice. I tried using fastclick.js but didn't work out. I have only added angularjs once through ionic.bundle.min.js.

I can't put the demo as this is confidential project.

And also, THIS PROBLEM ONLY OCCURS IN IOS, NOT IN ANDROID AND PC

Comment: Please add some code example  so we can see the usage of the `ng-click` and how you attached it to the DOM elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is problem, sometimes ng-click fires twice.

[please check: `https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1022`](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1022)

they have suggested multiple solutions

Comment: My first instinct is to use some kind of flag or counter variable to distinguish between the first and second events, possibly in conjunction with a `setTimeout()` call.

Comment: Yes, you can use the flag and check it.

Comment: It was working fine for a while but again it has stopped working and then its triggering the click twice